# How do I split date ranges into an array with a specific array from user input?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which i would like to get a range of data from when user inputs a range which falls into the values available.

```
$dat= array("2020-02-01","2020-02-05","2020-02-10","20-02-12","2020-02-15");
```

when user input search range of $start="2020-01-01" and $end="2020-02-07"

i want the `$dat` array to produce into `$currentdat == array("2020-02-01","2020-02-05");`alone

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's customary to attempt a solution and ask about your code rather than just listing your requirements. It's also customary to not [repost the exact same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069456/how-do-i-split-date-ranges-and-an-input) when the community closes a question. See [ask]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$dat= array("2020-02-01","2020-02-05","2020-02-10","20-02-12","2020-02-15");

//User input
$start ="2020-01-01";
$end="2020-02-07";

//Filter out dates between start and end date
$result = array_filter($dat, function($data_item) use($start,$end) {
    return $data_item >= $start && $data_item <= $end;
});
```

`$result` would output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2020-02-01
    [1] => 2020-02-05
)
```